# In low level, how is a character is printed to console

Tags: console, x86, operating-system, hardware, low-level-io

I am studying the source code of a simple OS (simple but real, one that can actually run on a x86 computer), and I am not sure the process that a character is sent to and displayed on the console monitor.

In the source code of the routine for sending the character, I see some inline assembly doing I/O operations (inb/outb). However, how is the character (an ASCII value) turned into a bitmap (an array of color values, say black and white pixels, that actually shows the character on the monitor screen). I can't find any form of mapping from character to bitmap in the OS source code. Does the process that turns ascii value to an array of pixels not happen in the OS? Is there a hardware device, such as a VGA chip, in charge of this? which one?

Comment: As far as I'm aware the baseline x86 PC spec includes support for text display modes, which I *assume* are character-mapped not bitmapped - the display card generates the character forms. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_mode#PC_common_text_modes

Comment: In an early version, I guess the BIOS can do that for you (there is, on x86, still a standardized set of INT 10h functions for this). But in a more sophisticated OS, it would probably be drivers that take over that task.

Comment: Could you tell us **exactly** what OS are you talking about and how does the _some inline assembly_ look like? The possible relevant answer depends on knowing **exactly** which piece of hardware is the _inb/outb_ talking to

Answer (score 1):

If a graphics mode is used, the system (or the bios) has to convert it to pixels and send it to the graphics adapter (mostly by copying the pixels to the graphics memory which is mapped).
If a text mode is used, the chars and the color attributes are sent to the graphics adapter (mostly by copying them to the graphics memory which is mapped).

In 16-bit real-mode the graphics memory is mapped to the segment a000h and the text memory is mapped to either b000h or b800h.
In 32-bit protected mode the graphics memory is mapped starting at the address a0000h and the text memory is mapped starting at the address b8000h