# How do computers display letters visually?

Tags: binary, computer-science

I understand that all letters are a result of bytes being transcribed into a human language we can read. What I don't understand is how it visually appears on the screen.

Sorry if that doesn't make much sense, but...what I mean is, you can tell a computer that 01000001 means "A", but how do you make the computer display "A"? How do you teach the computer to make this hyper-specific shape, and then display it on a screen? And how did somebody teach a computer that 01000001 was "A" in the first place?

My apologies if this isn't quite the right place to ask this question. Google doesn't really help, as the pages I've found just reiterates the whole "letters are made up of bytes" but doesn't explain how the computer knows what to do with those bytes and, as per this question, how it is taught what shape to make and how to display it. I'm new to the actual science behind computer hardware, so I can't really conceive what precise steps go into this sort of process.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You are asking how fonts work. Fonts map characters (stored as encoded bytes) to visual displays on the screen. Fonts also do an enormous amont of other things related to how vector graphics work. I would take a look at some introductory lessons on fonts, vector graphics, pixels and graphics programming.

Comment: What are you asking about, characters are displayed down to the bios level of a computer. But then redefined later.  Are you asking how it works on a fundamental level, or how to manipulate it on a higher level? Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28895188/in-low-level-how-is-a-character-is-printed-to-console

Comment: @AlexT. A fundamental level. As in what is happening inside the computer, how is it transferring the data in a readable manner to the machine. I will look at the thread you linked, thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_font#:~:text=A%20computer%20font%20is%20implemented,printing%2C%20is%20a%20screen%20font.